# EF Core 3.1 doesn't translate with a helper class on querying

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In .NET Core 2.2, I used to use a helper class that decrypts the data from the database and retrieves the user information, but now I can't. I get an exception saying that it can't' be translated.

That's the same logic used in .NET Core 2.2

```
var cp = await Context.Company
                      .Where(a => Encrypt.Decry(a.Email, a.Em) == login.Email 
                                  && login.Password == Hash.get(a.Password))
                      .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The exception :

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet.Where(c => Encrypt.Decry(value: c.Email, sec: c.Em) == __login_Email_0 && __login_Password_1 == Hash.get(c.Password))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."}

I don't get why I should explicitly used `AsEnumerable()`, `AsAsyncEnumerable()`, `ToList()`, or `ToListAsync()` ?

Update : So I tried to follow the example by adding `AsEnumerable` but it must be with await and I get an error on `where`

```
 var cp = await Context.Company.AsAsyncEnumerable().Where(a => Encrypt.Decry(a.Email, a.Em) == login.Email && login.Password == Hash.get(a.Password)).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: What error did you face on `Where` using `AsAsyncEnumerable`?

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` does not contain a definition for Where

Comment: If I remove the Async and only let `AsEnumerable` and changing to `SingleOrDefault` and the await I don't see the error anymore

Comment: Use `AsEnumerable` because `IAsyncEnumerable` : `This is an internal API that supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and not subject to the same compatibility standards as public APIs`. See here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/71a32cfd5a8c24dde5c8938f7eee4d8a14f29f5d/src/EFCore/Extensions/Internal/QueryableExtensions.cs

Comment: but what about the Async method? I can't access without using it

Comment: Also `Where` is an extension for `IEnumerable/IQueriable` not for `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: You need all users in memory so you can load them using `ToListAsync()`. Also you can cache it in memory to avoid loading this data for every request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210092/discussion-between-nathiel-paulino-and-mtkachenko).

Comment: There is no another way to do it in your infrastructure. You keep encrypted data in db and want to filter it by decrypted data. But encryption/decryption logic is complex C#. EF Core CAN'T translate it into SQL. So you have to load all data into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core can't translate `Encrypt.Decry` to SQL query. That's why you see the error. You can load all data into memory and then execute `Encrypt.Decry`.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval:

> Prior to version 3.0, Entity Framework Core supported client
>   evaluation anywhere in the query. For more information, see the
>   previous versions section.

Most likely now it's implemented like this to avoid unintentional client evaluation where a lot of data can be loaded into memory. Now you should explicitly configure client evaluation.

Comment: I did change to `Context.Company.AsEnumerable` but I can't get around using AsAsyncEnumerable.

Comment: You mean, I would have to Iterate the whole table to find a match?

Comment: @NathielPaulino `Context.Company.AsAsyncEnumerable` will stream all rows from the table into memory. Actually it worked the same way in `2.2` without `AsAsyncEnumerable`. But it was hidden from you.